# Weird shadow problem in Safari on website

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have built a website, but its acting funky in Safari with the menu. Please see the following video, where i show the problem. Its only in Safari, all other browsers its working perfectly fine

Video of the problem in Safari can be seen here https://vimeo.com/757367403

Here is my CSS, anybody know a trick or two to fix this problem ?

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700');

.elementor-nav-menu {
    align-items: center;
}

.elementor-nav-menu * {
    font-family: "Lato",  sans-serif !important; 
    
}

html[lang="kl-kl"] .elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(4) a {
    font-size:16px!important;
    padding: 15px 0px!important;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:first-child {
    background-color: #00aeef;
    zoom: 0.85;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #ef6500!important;
    width:170px!important;
    height:170px!important;
    zoom:0.9!important;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li a {
    flex-grow: 0!important;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(7n) {
    background-color: #e8b736!important;
    zoom:0.85;
}
.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #e8b736!important;
    width:220px;
    height:220px;
    padding:0 10px!important;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: #66cc9a!important;
    zoom:0.85;
}
html[lang="kl-kl"] .elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: #66cc9a!important;
    zoom:1.05!important;
    padding:0 0px!important;

    
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(4)   {
        margin:0 auto;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(5n){
    background-color: #00aeef;
    zoom:1.1;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(6) {
    width:180px!important;
    height:180px!important;
}
.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(5) {
    width:170px!important;
    height:170px!important;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li {
        -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: none;
      width:139px;
        height:139px;
        text-align:center;
        margin:0 10px!important;
    
      display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;
    
      filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75));
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li a {
    color:#fff!important;
    font-size: 18px!important;
    word-wrap: break-word!important;
    word-break: break-word!important;
    white-space: normal!important;
    line-height:26px;
    text-align:center;
}
.elementor-nav-menu > li a:hover {
    line-height:30px;
}

.elementor-nav-menu li a .sub-arrow {
    display:none;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > .sub-menu:nth-child(3) {
    background-color:red;
}

.elementor-nav-menu--dropdown li a {
    justify-content: center;
}

.elementor-nav-menu--dropdown {
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
    will-change: filter;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(2) ul {
    width: 300px!important;
    margin-top: 55px!important;
    background-color: #ef6500!important;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(3) ul {
    width: 300px!important;
    background-color: #e8b736!important;
    margin-top: 13px!important;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(4) ul {
    width: 300px!important;
    margin-top: 55px!important;
    background-color: #66cc9a!important;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(4) ul {
    width: 300px!important;
    margin-top: 50px!important;
}

.elementor-nav-menu > li:nth-child(5) ul {
    width: 300px!important;
    margin-top: 25px!important;
}

.elementor-sub-item:hover,
.elementor-sub-item.elementor-item-active {
    background-color: transparent!important;
    text-decoration: underline!important;
}
```

Comment: Site url? It would be easy to check and see what's wrong. Remove filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)); property from li and see if it works for you

Comment: The site is nakuusa.gl - If i remove that filter, all the shadows goes away all together.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```